# Unable to access pdf files under ./../../../assets/pdf/file.pdf Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, pdf, routes

In the angular application, i have placed the pdf under assets/pdf folder.
and in code

```html
<div class="container-fluid mt-2 mb-2">
    <a target="_blank" href="./../../../assets/pdf/MSW - Transition Briefing Slides v1.1.pdf">
        Transition Briefing Slides:Instructions on how to onboard, functions for
        Information Security Coordinator (ISC), FAQs, and scope of digitalPORT@SGTM
    </a>
</div>
```

When i click on hyperlink respective pdf will get open in the new tab. It works perfectly fine in the local environment.

In my Local
pdf file is getting opened in a new tab when I click on a hyperlink.

But when I try the same in other environments (UAT) the pdf is not getting opened and there is an error in console saying

> main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'assets/pdf/digitalPORT@SG%20-%20Quick%20Guide%20v0.3.pdf' Error:
>   Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'assets/pdf/digitalPORT@SG%20-%20Quick%20Guide%20v0.3.pdf'
>       at l.noMatchError (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n.selector (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n.error (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n._error (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n.error (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n._error (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n.error (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n._error (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n.error (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at n._error (main.3416feca6506333eea31.js:1)
>       at P (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:814)
>       at P (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:771)
>       at zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:873

My assumption was might be an issue with file name I have renamed the file name to test.pdf but does not work.

Comment: The problem here is your file path is wrong, before deploying your app change the path like "assets/pdf/MSW - Transition Briefing Slides v1.1.pdf."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<a target="_blank" href="./../../../assets/pdf/MSW - Transition Briefing Slides v1.1.pdf">` with folowing,

```html
<a target="_blank" href="assets/pdf/MSW - Transition Briefing Slides v1.1.pdf">
```

Asset folder stays at root level, hence always provide relative path from `assets` folder.

Comment: Thank you.I will try this.
but not sure how application identify pdf location ,the template is in \src\app\core\faq
and pdf is in "src\assets\pdf"

Comment: If you observe your code after build. You ll see assets folder at root level build. Hence relative path.

Comment: Thank you..I tried this approach but still same issue ..UAT is Linux server ..